# Extracting a substring of 3 starting from the back Java

Tags: java, string, substring, nodes

I want to extract a substring of length 3 from the back of a string in Java in Node application. So if I have 12345678 in a string, I want to get 678 in the first extraction, 345 in the second, and 12 in the last. This is just an example, it should work with any number of digits (which I will convert using parseInt()). THanks in advance!
This is what I have right now.

```
front=new IntNode(Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(digits.length()-3,digits.length())),null);
            back=front;
            
            for(int i=digits.length()-3;i>2;i-=2){                     
                   int sub=Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(i-3,i));
                   front.addNodeAfter(sub);
                   manyNodes++;
            }
```

But for 12345678998765 it's giving me 998,789,567,345,123,765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think the modulus operator offers a better way to do this:

```
int value = 12345678;
while (value > 0) {
    int last3 = value % 1000;
    System.out.println(last3);   // or console.log(last3) if using Node
    value = value / 1000;
}
```

This prints:

```
678
345
12
```

This logic here is to use modulus `%` of 1000 to find the last 3 digits.  Then, we divide by 1000 to lop off the last 3 digits and iterate again until there are no digits left.

Side note: I don't actually know whether you are using Java of Node here, but the above logic should work in either case.

**Edit:**

If you can't use the above approach for some reason, here is a trick you can use with `String#split` in Java:

```
String number = "12345679801234567890";
String[] numbers = number.replaceAll("(\\d{3})", "$1.").split("\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

This prints:

```
[123, 456, 798, 012, 345, 678, 90]
```

Comment: Thank You! Actually the numbers I am taking in are in string and I can't convert the string to an int or a long right away. How would that change the method that you have provided?

Comment: In Java use `String.valueOf(12345678)`.  In JavaScript, you could use `12345678 + ""` for a quick way to cast an integer to a string.

Comment: Yeah but I can't convert the whole thing to int or long at once (I'm not allowed to). This is for storing very very big numbers' 3 digits in a node at a time. So i have to convert 3 digits from the string as I go. Was just wondering how to do that with your way. :)

Comment: @UnderWRLDIntrovert Check the bottom of my answer for another option using Java, if you must work with a string.  It is regex based.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your i initialization, `int i=digits.length()-3` your i start with length - 3,

so if you have `12345678998765` , you start in number 7,

`int sub=Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(i-3,i));`

and then in here you take substring i - 3 to i, so you take 3 position behind 7, which means 998.

IMO you should use the modulus method in the other answer, just wanted to explain why your code didn't give you what you expected

Comment: That is because I got the first iteration outside the loop because I have to maintain a tail node as well. So instead of giving me the same number, it's giving me whatever I wrote above.

Comment: @UnderWRLDIntrovert yeah I just see it in your edit, I'm not familiar with how Node works, but it should be in how it add the first iteration to your overall iteration